# SAAS Based URL Mapping with Branding

Tags: url, branding, ux, saas, technical-seo

We have a SAAS based product with big vision & currently we are rebranding our product model. Is it the best SEO practice if i am going to use my Brand Name in my URL's of the main pages? **Eg:**

https://www.example.com/about
https://www.example.com/aboutexample

https://www.example.com/events
https://www.example.com/exampleevents

"example=My Brand Name"

Which one will be the best URL structure towards my TG?

Comment: Sorry but we already have a vast amount of questions regarding [URL structures](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=url+structure) on Pro Webmaster already and therefore do not need another.

Comment: Hi Simon, Plz help with this use case. We are trying to improve UX in organic SERP like the Adwords playing in dynamic Titles with giving us 2 Extra 15 characters field for customization of URL. Your answer will be highly appreciable. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Premnath321, thanks for contacting me via Twitter and sorry I didn't get back to you. Basically, there is never any need to repeat a keyword, so if that keyword appears in the domain name, repeating it is will add no more weight than the previous. So, in this case, you should always use `brand.com/events`, short URLs are better for users too! Never make your URLS for search engines, make them for users, short and to the point. Your titles, page meta description and page content is where you confirm URL and extend upon it.

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks a lot for your valuable comments. I am focusing only towards my TG. That's why I thought that it will be good if I put the my Brand name into some URL's. So in future when my TG search with query like "Brand Name Events" then they can land directly upon my event page which will be improve my Brand UX as well. Eg- I have searched into Google "Apple Events" & find the first result is - https://www.apple.com/in/apple-events/                                                   Plz advice. Thanks in Advance...